# React making an array of IDs from a checkboxes clicked

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to have a function run everytime I click a checkbox that adds the id for that it to an array so that I can then use that array to make an apollo call to a mutation in graphQL. What is currently happening is that every checkbox gets checked when I press any of them and arrays are consoled for every ID in the table. What am I doing wrong here?

```
const RouteLocationsSelector = (props) => {
    const {count} = useMileState()
    const dispatch = useMileDispatch()
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

    const handleClick = () => setChecked(!checked)

    var locationArray = [];

    function checkedLocations(id) {
      if (!locationArray.includes(id)) {
        return locationArray.push(id)

      } else {
        return locationArray.filter(function(e) { return e != id})
      }
    }

    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_LOCATIONS);

    if (loading) return <tbody><tr><td>Loading...</td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody>;
    if (error) return <tbody><tr><td>Errror, are you logged in?</td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody>;


    return data.locations.map(({ id, slug, gps }) => (
      <tbody key={id}>
        <tr>
          <td>{id}</td>
          <td>{slug}</td>
          <td>{gps}</td>
          <td>
          <input type="checkbox"
            onClick={handleClick}
            onChange={checkedLocations(id), console.log(locationArray)}/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    ))
  };

  export default RouteLocationsSelector;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably make the input box a fully controlled component by adding the checked property to it and setting it equal to the value of your local component state.

But also, since the check boxes are in a mapped array, you'll want to handle the state of whether or not they are in a checked state separately. So each checkbox should have it's own state stored in an array. So I imagine your useState hook should be an array of false values that get swapped to true for the index position of the checkbox that has changed.

Might also be a question of composition as well. You could abstract what is returned by the `map` function into it's own component so it can handle its own local state.

```
<input type="checkbox"
  checked={checked}
  onClick={handleClick}
  onChange={() => { checkedLocations(id); console.log(locationArray)}}
/>
```

I also imagine you'd probably want to add an anonymous function to the onChange event so that it doesn't fire everytime.